# SOLR Updated docs missing from query

Tags: solr

(Still a newbie; more questions)

I'm performing atomic updates on some SOLR 4 records via HTTP GET calls. This is working correctly after I fixed up some problems with my URLs.

But my original problem is still present: After I update a document, my search queries are no longer finding my updated docs.

Do I need to re-index an updated document? Do atomic updates cause a document to fall out of the index?

example:
I can search with this:

```
http://solrfarm.gateway.cco:8983/solr/records/select/?q=firstName:(tomas) recordType:(myrectype)&rows=100
```

and I get XML that looks like:

```
<doc>
<str name="id">CollName-7276748</str>
<str name="system">OHM Liens</str>
<long name="_version_">1464208859225653248</long>
<bool name="optout">false</bool>
</doc>
```

I want to change the optout value to "true" and that is happening with a URL that looks like this:

```
http://prodsolr01.cco:8983/solr/records/update?stream.body=%3Cadd%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22id%22%3ECollName-7276748%3C/field%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22optout%22%20update=%22set%22%20%3Etrue%3C/field%3E%3C/doc%3E%3C/add%3E&commit=true
```

Decoded and formatted:

```
stream.body=
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">CollName-7276748</field>
        <field name="optout" update="set" >true</field>
    </doc>
</add>
&commit=true
```

But, now when I run my original query, my record does not get returned.
If I search for the record explicitly, I get the record:

```
http://solrfarm.gateway.cco:8983/solr/records/select/?q=id:(%22CollName-7276748%22)%20&rows=100
```

So I'm confused as to why an updated record is no longer found by my query. Do I need to pass in all the original fields to my update command (i.e. the "firstName" and "lastName" fields that were indexed originally)?

Shouldn't it be enough to just perform the update?

Again, I'm a newbie and I'm probably not "getting" something basic, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you shared your full schema, how you indexed the document to being with and what the query result looks like from the search by id that works.

Comment: how come you search on one url and update on another?

Comment: For [atomic updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) all your fields must be specified as `stored="true"` and you must enable the update log. Probably this is handled as a regular update, which replaces the existing document. Since you didn't include the name field in your update, the new document doesn't match the original query.

Comment: Some updates: (trying to pry the production Schema.XML from IT)
1.The two servers are the same (Gateway -> prodsolr01)

2. Most of the indexed fields are not stored (only a handful are both stored/index=true). The fields that I was updating ARE stored, but the "firstName" field that I was querying is Indexed=true, but stored=false. So I beleive that I will need to re-submit this field (and the other similar fields) when performing the updates (basically resubmit the entire document).
More tests to follow.